# WARN : Your Hadoop installation does not include the StreamCapabilities class from HDFS-11644

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase, kerberos

I run a Kerberised Hbase Cluster over HDFS and I get this warning in the master log when I start hbase :

```
WARN  [Thread-15] util.CommonFSUtils: Your Hadoop installation does not include the StreamCapabilities class from HDFS-11644, so we will skip checking if any FSDataOutputStreams actually support hflush/hsync. If you are running on top of HDFS this probably just means you have an older version and this can be ignored. If you are running on top of an alternate FileSystem implementation you should manually verify that hflush and hsync are implemented; otherwise you risk data loss and hard to diagnose errors when our assumptions are violated.
```

I'm running HBase 2.0.5 and Hadoop 3.1.2

Does anyone have any idea what that means ?

Comment: Did you look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-11644?

Comment: Yes, people seem pretty confused in the comments. I am no expert in programming so I'm pretty confused about it too. It seems to affect Hadoop 2.9.0 and 3.0.0-alpha.
The only clue I have is that my HBase seems to think I use Hadoop 2.7 for some reason